# Read - check - write a flag in to database

Tags: java, database, oracle, locking

In program we can control multiple process accessing DB by using a Synchronized block. What approach we can use for below scenario.

- Read a column value from database - say `flag`
- If `flag` is `zero` update the flag column as `One`
- Do set of processing in the application which should be protected by **flag** ( Other instance of the application should not do this kind of operation until the `flag` is set to zero)
- Update the column `flag` again to `zero`

There are multiple instance of applications doing the above operation pointing to the same DB table. How we can synchronize this process across the instances of application?

**Research done**

Read about DB table lock and row locks,But in my case the read and write is two operation that should work as a unit of work from different application instance

Comment: There are various ways of interpreting your requirement, which have different solutions. So please clarify your question. Does the *"set of processing"* act on the table with the `flag` or on other tables/data-sets? Is there just one instance of the `flag` which applies universally across the application or are there multiple instances of the flag which identify multiple *"sets of processing"*?

Comment: The flag column is universal, If any of the application set the flag to 1 other application should not do any operation

Comment: So what do you want to happen if some other process tries to set the flag while somebody else is processing it?

Comment: Maybe look at SELECT ... FOR UPDATE ...

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you can't safely use values-in-columns as a way to "lock" things. If you need to generate a lock I suggest you use the routines in the DBMS_LOCK package, e.g.:

```
DECLARE
  strLock_handle  VARCHAR2(128);
  iResult         INTEGER;
  excpAllocate    EXCEPTION;

  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(excpAllocate, -20000);
BEGIN
  DBMS_LOCK.ALLOCATE_UNIQUE(lockname   => 'YOUR LOCK NAME',
                            lockhandle => strLock_handle);

  iResult := DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST(lockhandle        => strLock_handle,
                               lockmode          => DBMS_LOCK.X_MODE,  -- exclusive mode
                               timeout           => DBMS_LOCK.MAXWAIT,
                               release_on_commit => FALSE);

  IF iResult = 0 THEN
    -- Do what you need to do exclusively here - nothing else will be able to enter this
    -- section as they'll stall on the DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST call above.

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('This is a stupid piece of example code');

    -- Note: if we changed the RELEASE_ON_COMMIT parameter passed to DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST
    -- above to TRUE, the following COMMIT would release all locks held
    -- by this process for which RELEASE_ON_COMMIT was TRUE.

    COMMIT;

    -- Release the lock acquired above. This will allow one of the (possibly
    -- many) processes stalled on the DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST above to proceed.

    iResult := DBMS_LOCK.RELEASE(strLock_handle);
  ELSE
    -- Lock was not acquired. Reasons are:
    --   iResult   Reason
    --   1         Timeout
    --   2         Deadlock
    --   3         Parameter error
    --   4         Already own lock specified
    --   5         Illegal lock handle

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DBMS_LOCK.REQUEST failed - iResult = ' || iResult);
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN excpAllocate THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DBMS_LOCK.ALLOCATE failed : ' || SQLCODE || ' ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Nice example Bob. Unfortunately I don't believe it fulfills his requirement "_read and write is two operation that should work as a unit of work from different application instance_". His requirements are somewhat confusing: he doesn't want  other instances of the application to be able to do something, but he wants multiple instances of the application to be able to to do something. How do you know which instances are OK for update, and which aren't. Unless the multiple instances are launched within your _Do what you need to do exclusively here_ section.